# i have WordPress site i need to zip and download some images from some posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and i use this site for image content. I made some changes at it.

I made a plugin to make a post for **an image** by its link, and then i made a new page to show the new posts -10 days ago. I use a code and short code it to view the -10 days posts at the page.  I need to download the images from the -10 days posts in zip file.

How could i do that ?

This is the code for the -10 days posts. written in function.php file for the theme.

```
function tendays_posts_shortcode($atts) {
//defaults
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'what' => 'imagelinks',
    'days' => '-10 Days',
), $atts ) );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $atts['what'],
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($atts['days']))
    )
);
query_posts($args);

// Reset and setup variables
$output = '';
$temp_title = '';
$temp_link = '';

// the loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $post_img_maisra = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
  $temp_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
  $temp_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $output .= "<p class='ten-days-post'><a href='$temp_link'><img class='ten-days-img' width:'100px' 
  height='100'' src='$post_img_maisra'/> $temp_title</a> </p>";
  endwhile; else:

  $output .= "";

 endif;

 wp_reset_query();
 return $output;}
 add_shortcode('tendays_posts','tendays_posts_shortcode');
```